# Cómo calculo el total de los productos que voy agregando al carrito? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JS y quiero sumar a un total los productos que voy agregando al carrito. Pero estoy muy perdido a la hora de hacerlo.
Les dejo el código que tengo.

[image: Código JS]

Comment: Coloca tu codigo en Vez de una imagen, para que sea más sencillo ayudarte

Comment: El código va como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: Se nos hace muy dificil leer y provar la imagen para reclear tu problema, pero si lo colocas todo en texto se nos hace mas facil. Tambien aconsejo agregar una descripción de lo que está fallando y como quieres que quede.

Answer (score 1):

Si el carrito es `$("#contenedorCards")`, solo necesitas acceder al conjunto de elementos que contiene con el método [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) y obtener el total de estos con la propiedad [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/).

Te sugiero que la próxima vez coloques el código como texto en lugar de imagen, y solo la parte crítica.